# PHPMyAdmin cannot connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, database-connection, lamp

I installed the lampp sever on my local in linux OS,
but its giving error while opening phpmyadmin.

```
#2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)
```

Comment: If you can connect with another client, check the PHPMyAdmin config file. If not, first solve that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See services mysqld enabled or disabled.

Comment: how to see?? please be descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

check if MySQL is running with this command

mysqladmin -u root -p status

if it is running it will ask for your password otherwise it will spit out an error

Comment: yes,it asking for password ,I have to enter mysqlpassword. but I didnt assign any password,when I enter its giving error
connect to server at localhost failed.

Comment: did you set a password when you installed mysql?

Comment: no I didnt assign a pwd,can't connect to localmysql sever through socket

Comment: set a password then

mysql -u root
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('your_new_password');

Comment: after enterting pwd its giviing following error:
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!

Comment: which linux distro are you using?